# custom cursor not showing up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to c# and unity, and I was trying to make a custom cursor by attaching this code to the cursor gameobject. In the inspector, I can see that the gameobject is clearly following the mouse, but the gameobject just disappears when I start the game.

```
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 cursorPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        transform.position = cursorPosition;
    
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that `Cursor.visible = false;` called at the start has something to do with it?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I don't think so because it wasn't working before I added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this function to set a new cursor Texture `Cursor.SetCursor(Texture2D,CursorMode)`" if you want to do it at runtime.
Also you can set the default cursor on menu **Edit > Project Settings > Player > Default cursor**

[Documentation of this Method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.SetCursor.html)

Also you have to configure the Texture import to be a type cursor Texture, you can find the documentation of how set up a Texture cursor on this link:

[Texture type Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html#cursor)